# Dropdown to execute file upload using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to trigger file upload when someone clicks 'add glass'
this is what I did and it doesn't work.

```js
 $('select[name="dropdown"]').change(function(){



  if ($(this).val() == "4"){
        $('input[type=file]').trigger('click');

  }    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><select name="dropdown" size=1>
     <option value="1">Select</option>
     <option value="4">Add Glass</option>
     </select>​</td>
     <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="display: none;" accept="image/*">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a option as select it will work.... because you are using on change event... The event will work only when you change the select option...

```js
 $('select[name="dropdown"]').change(function(){



  if ($(this).val() == "4"){
        $('input[type=file]').trigger('click');

  }    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><select name="dropdown" size=1>
<option value="1">Select</option>
 <option value="4">Add Glass</option>
 </select>​</td>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="display: none;" accept="image/*">
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to trigger my file upload? Nothing happens when I do that.

Comment: There is no error. Whatever you suggested didn't work on a plain HTML file I did exactly what you said.

Comment: Did you include jquery.js script?please check.. otherwise share your code once again...

Comment: Yes I have. Have you tested the answer ? Is it working for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158653/discussion-between-nandhi-kumar-and-dilli).

Answer (score 0):

You have only one option so change event not called.

You Should add an empty option at the top of your select box, or perhaps an option that just says -Select-.

```js
 $('select[name="dropdown"]').change(function(){
  if ($(this).val() == "4"){
     $('#file').trigger('click');
  }    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
<select name="dropdown" size=1>
  <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  <option value="4">Add Glass</option>
</select>
</td>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="display: none;" accept="image/*">
```